# how to search unicode characters on php?

Tags: php, codeigniter, unicode

it's fine to make english text search on php but how do we make unicode search in php which is not english language ? I am building a site which has different language than english. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like [mb_strpos()](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strpos.php)